# Удаление стикеров discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Пытаюсь удалить все стикеры одной командой, но выводит ошибку

AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'stickers'

Как исправить? Вот код который я имею

```
async def ds(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    for Sticker in ctx.guild.stickers:
        await Sticker.delete()
```

Comment: У класса Guild в discord py попросту нет атрибута stickers

Comment: Вы хотите все стикеры удалить или стикеры из сообщения?

Comment: хочу именно все стикеры, я догадывался что нет такого атрибута но в js такую функцию провернуть можно поэтому появились сомнения

Comment: Боюсь, что нельзя удалить. Удаление есть у эмодзи, но не у стикеров

Comment: благодарю за помощь